# Need to count the number of emails in a string using Capybara/RSpec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

So I have an application which holds multiple entries that are strings of comma separated emails.  The strings live in text area elements where they can be modified.  The application uses JavaScript to modify these strings, I need to use Capybara to watch verify that a target string has the correct number of emails in it.  To illustrate what I mean here's my Cucumber (assuming the target list starts with a 5 email string):

```
When I remove the 3rd email under list one
Then I should see 4 emails under list one
When I click the "Cancel" button for list one
Then I should see 5 emails under list one
```

I can pretty easily grab the string with Capybara like so:

```
expect(page).to have_css(".css-selectors textarea")
```

but I don't know what to do from there.  I need to be able to assert that the number of emails in the string is in fact changing to the desired number.  I need to split the string and count the number of emails to see if they match the target number, but everything I've tried leads to a race condition where Capybara checks the value before the JS can finish updating.  I've looked into passing a filter block to the have_css call but I can't find documentation on how that would work, or if it's even the right tactic.  And so I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: Can you show the code that extracts the textareas' values so that we can see on what data you operate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the emails are in one element your inclination to use a filter block is exactly correct. The filter block receives each element that matches the initial selector and needs to return whether or not it matches whatever extra filtering you wish to do (true/false).  Therefore, to check that the element had a string (value not text since it's a form field) with 4 comma separated items it would be something like

```
expect(page).to have_css(".css-selectors textarea"){ |ta|
  ta.value.split(',').size == 4
}
```

This will then use Capybaras waiting/retrying behavior while also performing the extra step of checking for a matching number of comma separated items in the text of the element, thereby getting around the race condition.

Your check could also be performed by using a regex for the `with` option of the field selector, along the lines of

```
expect(page).to have_field(type: 'textarea', with: /^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$/)
```

or fillable_field selector

```
expect(page).to have_selector(:fillable_field, type: 'textarea', with: /^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$/)
```

Those don't currently scope to the `.css-selectors` element but you could do that with `within` or a chained find. You could also ensure a unique element by passing the id/name/label text of the element. Obviously you could make the regex more complicated if you want to actually verify the text strings are emails, etc.

Comment: And that seems to have done the trick.  Thanks for the clarification on filter blocks, they look amazingly useful.

Comment: @JonathonNordquist You're welcome, don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered if you don't need any more info.